# Jump to a specific entry not working for several browser

Tags: html, anchor

i was working with Screen and some Qwebkit based browser. I do thumbnails of specific entrys of a webpage via Achnor. That worked fine till some days.
The issue is that a lot of webbrowsers (including my crawler) aren't able to Jump to a specific Anchor of a post entry. This issue occours only on this specific Website by Blizzard Entertainment.

I took a look into the webpage several times with firebug but i can't see the reason for the Bug. I hope that someone is able to tell me whats wrong with it.

http://eu.battle.net/hearthstone/de/forum/topic/14899382319?page=4#69

Comment: could be because of id starting with a number... Anyway this is a problem for HTML4 and not for 5 which is presented on the page given

Comment: Thanks a lot Simon, i will adress this to the Web Team.